# Set include path for other makefiles

Tags: makefile

From [the makefile's reference page for include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) :

> If the specified name does not start with a slash, and the file is not
>   found in the current directory, several other directories are
>   searched. First, any directories you have specified with the ‘-I’ or
>   ‘--include-dir’ option are searched (see Summary of Options). Then the
>   following directories (if they exist) are searched, in this order:
>   prefix/include (normally /usr/local/include 1) /usr/gnu/include,
>   /usr/local/include, /usr/include.

So, is there a way to set the include path from the makefile, from which other makefiles are included?

I would not like to have to pass `--include-dir` to make every time I call it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to add those flags to the `MAKEFLAGS` variable in the makefile itself.

From [Communicating Options to a Sub-`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion):

> The `MAKEFLAGS` variable can also be useful if you want to have certain options, such as ‘`-k`’ (see Summary of Options), set each time you run `make`. You simply put a value for `MAKEFLAGS` in your environment. You can also set `MAKEFLAGS` in a makefile, to specify additional flags that should also be in effect for that makefile. (Note that you cannot use `MFLAGS` this way. That variable is set only for compatibility; make does not interpret a value you set for it in any way.)

But a quick test seems to indicate that this doesn't actually work.

I thought `VPATH`/`vpath` might be of use here but some quick testing of that seems to indicate it isn't.

Which means, as far as I can tell, that if you don't want to specify them on the command line manually each run that you get to use a shell script/function/etc. which handles adding them for you.

Though one last quick test seems to indicate that despite the file setting of `MAKEFLAGS` not working the environment variable route does work. So you could set `MAKEFLAGS` in the environment and make should use that correctly.

Comment: Ok, I will play a bit with MAKEFLAGS, and see if I can use it. vpath is for headers include, not makefiles include. Thanks

Comment: `vpath` is for "prerequisites". It was a long shot to think that make might use it since it tries to build makefiles. You might be able to get it to work with a `%.mk: %.mk ; cp $^ $@` rule in the makefile also but I didn't try that.

Comment: Setting `MAKEFLAGS` in the makefile won't work, because changes to the value of `MAKEFLAGS` are only parsed after all the makefiles are read in, not every time the `MAKEFLAGS` variable is set.  By the time make has parsed all the makefiles, adding new include directories doesn't help obviously.

Comment: @MadScientist I thought something like that might be the case. I also figured it might be possible that make would try again with the modified paths during the "see if they can be built" phase but clearly that doesn't happen and I'm not sure it should. vpath working (or a specific directive for this instead) might be a nice way to handle this though (though if that `%.mk : %.mk` copy target works that might be good enough most of the time).

Comment: Yes, the most common idea for implementing this enhancement is to use `VPATH` to search for included files.  I think there's a bug on Savannah about this.